# map.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize()); is not working

Tags: postgresql, openlayers, geojson, extents, ajax

I would like to know how to get all multipolygon features i.e all districts features display on my web map when I select state from dropdown list.

This is the query i wrote to get all districts features:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(t1.*) as extent FROM ricepest.district t1 
WHERE state = 'PUNJAB';
```

I have this code, I want to get all multipolygon features stored in a table in PostgreSQL database, I retreive the GeoJSON format succesfully, but I cannot see all these multipolygon features at a time on my web map.

The four files are included below: (HTML file + service repository file + controller file + js file)

File : app.jsp to load the map

```
<div class="container">
  <div tabindex="1" id="map" class="map"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputState">State</label> 
    <select class="form-control" id="inputState" onchange="IIRR.getDist();">
      <option value="SelectState">-- Select State --</option>
      <option value="AP">AndhraPradesh</option>
      <option value="KA">Karnataka</option>
      <option value="PB">Punjab</option>
      <option value="TS">Telangana</option>
    </select>
 </div>
</div>
```

File service repository:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(t1.*) as extent FROM ricepest.district t1 where state = :val")
List<GetFeature> getFeatureByStateIdService(@Param("val") String val);
```

File controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/feature")
public ResponseEntity<List<GetFeature>> getFeatureByStateIdService(@RequestBody RequestInputs reqInputs) {
    System.out.println("The state input value for getFeature : " + reqInputs.getState_id());
    List<GetFeature> extent = pestServiceRepository.getFeatureByStateIdService(reqInputs.getState_id());        
    if (!extent.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(extent, HttpStatus.OK);
    } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

File javascript:

```
var IIRR = {

getDist: function() {
    var val = {
        state_id: $("#inputState").val()
    };      

    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/district',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(val),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(item) {
            var htmlString = "<option value='0'>-- Select District--</option>";
            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                htmlString = htmlString + "<option value='" + item[i].districtId + "'>" + item[i].district + "</option>";
            }
            $("#inputDistrict").html(htmlString);
            IIRR.fitExtent($("#inputState option:selected").text(), $("#inputDistrict option:selected").text());
        },          
    });
},

highlightStyle: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: '#f00',
        width: 1
    }),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.1)'
    }),
    text: new ol.style.Text({
        font: '14px Calibri,sans-serif',
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: '#000000'
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#FFFF99',
            width: 3.5
        })
    })
}),


getFeature: function(state, dist) {
    
    var formData = {
        state_id: state.toUpperCase(),
        dist: dist.toUpperCase(),           
    };
    
    var Extent = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "api/feature",
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", jqXHR.responseJSON.error);
        }
    }).responseJSON;
    return (Extent.length != 0) ? Extent[0].extent : null;
},

fitExtent: function(st_val, dist_val) {
    const feat = IIRR.getFeature(st_val, dist_val);
    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    var feature = format.readFeatures(feat);
    vectorSource.clear();
    vectorSource.addFeatures(feature);
    vectorLayer.setStyle(IIRR.highlightStyle);
    console.log(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent());

    map.getLayers().forEach(layer => {
        if (layer && layer.get('name') === 'style') {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        }
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    map.getView().fit(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent(), map.getSize());
}}
```

Comment: You have a lot of debugging console logs. Where it goes wrong? Please edit your question with additional info about which part does not work.

Comment: I am getting all districts data from getFeature function i.e at console.log(result); .But I cannot see all districts features view on my map from fitExtent function i.e at console.log(vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent()); . Please help me

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/464392/edit) your question and add info from your comment into the body of the question.

Comment: Info from your comment is still not included in the body of the question.